# CXX translate - const char * to rust equivalent

Tags: c++, rust, rust-cargo

I am writing an integration of C++ and Rust via CXX

https://cxx.rs/index.html

The C++ function signature in `myclient.h`

```
    public:
        bool connect(const char * host, int port, int clientId = 0);
```

What do I put in the `main.rs` in order to have it callable from rust?  I've tried a lot of combos

```
        fn connect(host: &mut , port: u64, clientId: u64 ) -> bool;
        fn connect(host: *char , port: u64, clientId: u64 ) -> bool;
        fn connect(host: *const char , port: u64, clientId: u64 ) -> bool;
```

all of these error out.. not very good at C++ or Rust so.. just hoping someone can point me to how to convert this .. thanks!

```
  error[cxxbridge]: unsupported type: char
     ┌─ src/main.rs:15:33
     │
  15 │         fn connect(host: *const char , port: u64, clientId: u64 ) -> bool;
     │                                 ^^^^ unsupported type
```

### EDIT :

After getting a bit closer.. it seems to complain about `pointer argument requires that the function be marked unsafe`

```
#[cxx::bridge(namespace = "com::enserio")]
mod ffi {

    unsafe extern "C++" {
        include!("twsapi_grpc_server/include/twsapi-client.h");
        include!("twsapi_grpc_server/include/AvailableAlgoParams.h");
        include!("twsapi_grpc_server/include/AccountSummaryTags.h");
        include!("twsapi_grpc_server/include/Utils.h");

        type TWSApiClient;

        fn new_twsapi_client() -> UniquePtr<TWSApiClient>;
        
        fn init_connect(&self, host: *const c_char , port: i32, client_id: i32) -> bool;
   }
}
```

```
error[cxxbridge]: pointer argument requires that the function be marked unsafe
     ┌─ src/main.rs:16:32
     │
  16 │         fn init_connect(&self, host: *const c_char , port: i32, client_id: i32) -> bool;
     │                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ pointer argument requires that the function be marked unsafe
```

Comment: Usually symbols exported with `extern "C"` are used to call something from another language. Since you have `public` in your C++ code, the function there is a member. There are no member functions in *C*.

Comment: @SergeyKolesnik I've updated an edit to indicate more information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`char` in rust is not what you want (in rust char is a unicode chacrter, while in C it is a single byte).

What you want is `libc::c_char`.

```
use libc::c_char;
extern "C" fn connect(host: *const c_char , port: u64, clientId: u64 ) -> bool {
    true
}
```

However I'm not *sure* the `bool` as the return type will work reliably, I'd probably return a type with a concrete size like `u32` instead.

Comment: `libc::c_char` is actually `core::ffi::c_char`, `i8` on x86(32, 64), so `const char*` is `*const i8` in Rust

Comment: I am seeing `pointer argument requires that the function be marked unsafe` .. even tho the entire thing is marked as unsafe .. will update the post

Comment: setting to closed.. I successfully got it working with your help AND adding a few other fixes... like adding an `unsafe` right on the method itself